# SQL Add database to all table references

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Instead of typing 'NXT_US.dbo.' over and over, how else could I do this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                      NXT_US.dbo.icsp.prod, NXT_US.dbo.icsp.descrip##1, NXT_US.dbo.icsp.descrip##2, NXT_US.dbo.icsw.whse, NXT_US.dbo.sastn.descrip AS branch, NXT_US.dbo.icsw.qtyonhand, NXT_US.dbo.icsp.unitstock AS UOM, NXT_US.dbo.apsv.vendno AS VendorNumber, 
                      NXT_US.dbo.apsv.name AS VendorName, NXT_US.dbo.icsp.prodcat, NXT_US.dbo.sasta.descrip, NXT_US.dbo.icsw.prodline, NXT_US.dbo.icsw.statustype, NXT_US.dbo.icsw.lastinvdt, NXT_US.dbo.oeel.invoicedt, NXT_US.dbo.icsw.avgcost, NXT_US.dbo.oeel.vendno, 
                      NXT_US.dbo.icsw.avgcost * NXT_US.dbo.icsw.qtyonhand AS ExtCost, NXT_US.dbo.oeel.prodcost, NXT_US.dbo.oeel.orderno
INTO InventoryView
FROM         NXT_US.dbo.sasta INNER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.icsp ON NXT_US.dbo.sasta.codeval = NXT_US.dbo.icsp.prodcat LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.icswu ON NXT_US.dbo.icsp.prod = NXT_US.dbo.icswu.prod LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.icsw LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.oeel ON NXT_US.dbo.icsw.lastinvdt = NXT_US.dbo.oeel.invoicedt AND NXT_US.dbo.icsw.whse = NXT_US.dbo.oeel.whse AND NXT_US.dbo.icsw.prod = NXT_US.dbo.oeel.shipprod RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.sastn RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.icsd ON NXT_US.dbo.sastn.cono = NXT_US.dbo.icsd.cono AND NXT_US.dbo.sastn.codeval = NXT_US.dbo.icsd.divno ON NXT_US.dbo.icsw.whse = NXT_US.dbo.icsd.whse ON NXT_US.dbo.icsp.prod = NXT_US.dbo.icsw.prod LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.apsv ON NXT_US.dbo.icsw.arpvendno = NXT_US.dbo.apsv.vendno
WHERE     (NXT_US.dbo.sasta.cono = '1') AND (NXT_US.dbo.sasta.codeiden = 'c') AND (NXT_US.dbo.icsw.statustype = 's') AND (NXT_US.dbo.icsp.cono = '1') AND (NXT_US.dbo.sastn.codeiden = 'V') and NXT_US.dbo.icsw.whse = 'G010'
```

Comment: Once the table is referenced then you can refer to it by just the table name. Also you may want to read up on [aliases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=SQL.105).aspx).

Comment: so NXT_US is database and dbo is the schema.  if all tables are in the same db and same schema then  what is the reason you want to add this DB and schema as prefix to all table name. using a fully qualified object name is good practice but that's what you have to do if it is just development practice you have in your company.

Answer (score 0):

Alias each table the first time you use it in your FROM clause. Then you can use the alias in your SELECT, WHERE, GROUP BY clauses. Here is the example (but use better aliases than the generic ones I put here):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                      t2.prod, t2.descrip##1, t2.descrip##2, t4.whse, t6.descrip AS branch, t4.qtyonhand, t2.unitstock AS UOM, t8.vendno AS VendorNumber, 
                      t8.name AS VendorName, t2.prodcat, t1.descrip, t4.prodline, t4.statustype, t4.lastinvdt, t5.invoicedt, t4.avgcost, t5.vendno, 
                      t4.avgcost * t4.qtyonhand AS ExtCost, t5.prodcost, t5.orderno
INTO InventoryView
FROM         NXT_US.dbo.sasta AS t1 INNER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.icsp AS t2 ON t1.codeval = t2.prodcat LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.icswu AS t3 ON t2.prod = t3.prod LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.icsw AS t4 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.oeel AS t5 ON t4.lastinvdt = t5.invoicedt AND t4.whse = t5.whse AND t4.prod = t5.shipprod RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.sastn AS t6 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.icsd AS t7 ON t6.cono = t7.cono AND t6.codeval = t7.divno ON t4.whse = t7.whse ON t2.prod = t4.prod LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      NXT_US.dbo.apsv AS t8 ON t4.arpvendno = t8.vendno
WHERE     (t1.cono = '1') AND (t1.codeiden = 'c') AND (t4.statustype = 's') AND (t2.cono = '1') AND (t6.codeiden = 'V') and t4.whse = 'G010'
```